# How to add a page indicator inside the navigation bar?

Tags: ios

Like twitter did:

[image]

I have a PageViewController inside a UITabBarController which in turn is inside a UINavigationController.

Could anyone tell me how to show the page indicator inside the navigation bar?

Comment: They most likely write their own view.

Comment: You can use self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView, which is a UIView. Create custom implementation of page indicator and set it to titleView. However you also need to take care of how the interaction between your custom title page indicator view and other components will take place?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit: I just figured out that navigationController.viewControllers only contains the stack.
I will post an edit in a minute

Edit 2: Well, it seems that you have to know the number of view controllers before hand.

Maybe not the best solution, but it works for me. Just tried :)

```
@interface ViewController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPageControl *pageControl;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
    navController.delegate = self;

    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.2
                                                               green:.4
                                                                blue:.9
                                                               alpha:1];

    CGSize navBarSize = navController.navigationBar.bounds.size;
    CGPoint origin = CGPointMake( navBarSize.width/2, navBarSize.height/2 );

    self.pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y,
                                                                       0, 0)];

    //Or whatever number of viewcontrollers you have
    [self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:2];

    [navController.navigationBar addSubview:self.pageControl];

    navController.delegate = self;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    int index = [navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    self.pageControl.currentPage = index;
}

@end
```

Here are some screenshots.

[image: First View]
[image: Second view]

Comment: It should not be difficult to make this work for UIPageViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for those looking for a **Swift** solution.

(adjust formatting to your own needs)

[image]

```
class NavigationControllerWithPageControl: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    let numberOfPages: Int

    init(rootViewController: UIViewController, numberOfPages: Int) {
        self.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        delegate = self
        navigationBar.addSubview(pageControl)
        pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        pageControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    lazy var pageControl: UIPageControl = {
        let navBarsize = navigationBar.bounds.size
        let origin = CGPoint(x: navBarsize.width/2, y: navBarsize.height/2)
        let pc = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: origin.x, y: origin.y, width: 100, height: 20))
        pc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pc.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        pc.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .black
        pc.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white//.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        pc.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return pc
    }()

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        let index = navigationController.viewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) ?? NSNotFound
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.pageControl.currentPage = index
            guard let pageControlSubviews = self?.pageControl.subviews.enumerated() else {return}
            for (_, dotView) in pageControlSubviews {
                dotView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
                dotView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                dotView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let navigationViewController = NavigationControllerWithPageControl(rootViewController: SomeViewController(), numberOfPages: 7)
present(navigationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```