# UIPageViewController page indicator position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

Recently I coded this little Tutorial about UIPageViewController:
http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

After this tutorial I was wondering if I can change the position of the Page Indicators to the top of the screen.

Does anyone know how?

EDIT

Thank you for your help so far. i followed this post:
[How to put the UIPageControl element on top of the sliding pages within a UIPageViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045630/how-to-put-the-uipagecontrol-element-on-top-of-the-sliding-pages-within-a-uipage/21048603#21048603)

Now i have the page Control on the top, but some strange things happen:
If you swipe from page 1 to page 2 the indicator indicates that the user is on page 3.
i put in a NSLog which shows me the current index and it changes while swipe to the next page from 0 to 1 and than to 2.

Does anybody know why?

Current Code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;

@end

@implementation APPViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

    APPChildViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.pageControl];


    //Or whatever number of viewcontrollers you have
    [self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:5];

    }

- (APPChildViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    APPChildViewController *childViewController = [[APPChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"APPChildViewController" bundle:nil];
    childViewController.index = index;

    return childViewController;

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(APPChildViewController *)viewController index];

    if (index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Decrease the index by 1 to return
    index--;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:index];

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(APPChildViewController *)viewController index];

    index++;
    [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:index];

    if (index == 5) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

}
```

AppChildViewController:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger index;    
- (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        switch(self.index)
        {
            case zero: {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page1.png"];
                NSLog(@"%d",self.index);
                break;
            }
            case one: {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page2.png"];
                NSLog(@"%d",self.index);
                break;
            }
            case two: {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page3.png"];
                NSLog(@"%d",self.index);
                break;
            }
            case three: {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page4.png"];
                NSLog(@"%d",self.index);
                break;
            }
            default: {
                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page5.png"];
                NSLog(@"%d",self.index);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here is the answer for the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21048603/3532040

Comment: i used this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073891/how-to-add-a-page-indicator-inside-the-navigation-bar to het it on top

Comment: Hi, I think best thing you can do is create a new question or change the header of the question?

Comment: Have you figured out the issue with indexing the page? I've had the same problem with my custom page indicator.. even though I've followed the example provided in several tutorials.

Comment: assuming your parameter viewControllerAfterViewController is the next view controller and your are at index 0, viewControllerAfterViewController's index should be 1, if you add another 1 to the index (`index++`), it will be 2

Answer (score 1):

In our app, I put the page indicator at the top of a page view controller’s view by turning the view upside-down. This is really silly, and I would not recommend using this technique unless you’re confident. It goes something like this:

```
[pageWrapperView setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate([pagingView transform], M_PI)];
```

Where the page view controller’s view is a subview of `pageWrapperView`.

Then you’ll need to flip the content views too, so they are the right way up.

I have [a demo on Github where this technique is used to put a tab bar at the top of the screen](https://github.com/douglashill/TopTabs).

Comment: This made me laugh :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly creating the page control and adding it the view with a given frame such as:

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[self.view addSubView:pageControl];
```

... or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can't handle the page index in `viewControllerAfterViewController` and `viewControllerBeforeViewController` because they are not necesseraly called when the page change, and you won't have the correct index.

Instead I suggest you to handle it in `pageViewController: didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:`

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {
    if (finished) {
        APPChildViewController *childViewController = [pageViewController.viewControllers firstObject];
        [self.pageControl setCurrentPage:childViewController.index];
    }
}
```