# How to add page control using UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I want to add the `UIPageControl` at the top of navigation bar.

I had added the `UIPageControl`, but its not working as per changing the page.

Is it possible to change the `UIPageControl` while using `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`?

Comment: CHECK THIS LINK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073891/how-to-add-a-page-indicator-inside-the-navigation-bar

Comment: thank you @KathiravanG i tried that link, but its not changing as i change the page.Its only taking the current page index.Any other solution???

Comment: What is the issue you facing while changing page.

Comment: The content of the next view appears, but only UIPageControl remains at its original position